# unwind segue performing by runtime issue

Tags: ios, swift, unwind-segue

Apple says about ***unwind(for:towards:)*** method (which called when an unwind segue transitions to a new view controller):

> During the execution of an unwind segue, UIKit calls this method on
> any view controllers in the unwind path to give them an opportunity to
> reconfigure themselves.

ok. I tried to check this fact. in the example there are 4 view controllers each was pushed. So on the outermost view controller i touched unwind button (@ibaction unwind method was implemented in the root view controller (pink)). Each child is ViewController: UIViewController class. And navigation controller is custon NavigationControlllerClass with unwind(for:towrds) and dismiss methods overrode to print the have been called.
But [image: []
So. According to apple words unwind(for:towards:) have to be called 4 times on ViewController: UIViewController class, and 1 times on CustomNavitaionController class. But it has been called only once on Viewcontroller class and only once on CustomNavigationController class. Why so??? Apple says on any...(((

```
  class ViewController : UIViewController {

@IBAction func doUnwind(_ sender:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    
}

override func allowedChildrenForUnwinding(from source: UIStoryboardUnwindSegueSource) -> [UIViewController] {
    let result = super.allowedChildrenForUnwinding(from: source)
    print("\(self) \(#function) \(result)")
    return result
}

override func unwind(for unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue, towards subsequentVC: UIViewController) {
    print("\(self)  \(subsequentVC)")
    super.unwind(for: unwindSegue, towards: subsequentVC)
}

override func canPerformUnwindSegueAction(_ action: Selector, from fromViewController: UIViewController, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    var result = super.canPerformUnwindSegueAction(action, from: fromViewController, sender: sender)
    return result
}

override func dismiss(animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    print("\(self) \(#function)")
    super.dismiss(animated:animated, completion: completion)
}

override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    let result = super.shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier: identifier, sender: sender)
    if identifier == "unwind" {
        print("\(self) \(#function) \(result)")
    }
    return result
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "unwind" {
        print("\(self) \(#function)")
    }
}    
}





class MyNavController : UINavigationController {

override func allowedChildrenForUnwinding(from source: UIStoryboardUnwindSegueSource) -> [UIViewController] {
    let result = super.allowedChildrenForUnwinding(from: source)
    print("\(type(of:self)) \(#function) \(result)")
    return result
}

override func unwind(for unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue, towards subsequentVC: UIViewController) {
    print("\(type(of:self)) \(#function) \(subsequentVC)")
    super.unwind(for: unwindSegue, towards: subsequentVC)
}

override func canPerformUnwindSegueAction(_ action: Selector, from fromViewController: UIViewController, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    let result = super.canPerformUnwindSegueAction(action, from: fromViewController, sender: sender)
    print("\(type(of:self)) \(#function) \(action) \(result)")
    return result
}

override func dismiss(animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    print("\(type(of:self)) \(#function)")
    super.dismiss(animated:animated, completion: completion)
}

override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    let result = super.shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier: identifier, sender: sender)
    if identifier == "unwind" {
        print("\(type(of:self)) \(#function) \(result)")
    }
    return result
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "unwind" {
        print("\(type(of:self)) \(#function)")
    }
}

override func popToViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) -> [UIViewController]? {
    print("\(type(of:self)) \(#function) \(viewController)")
    return super.popToViewController(viewController, animated:animated)
}    
 }
```

Comment: @matt on page 400 you wrote: "• If it encounters a parent view controller on the path, the runtime tells it to unwind(for:towards:).
The second parameter of unwind(for:towards:) is the direct child of this parent view controller leading down the branch where the destination lives. This child might or might not be the destination, but that’s no concern of this parent view controller. Its job is merely to get us onto that branch, whatever that may mean for this kind of parent view controller."  but in fact when i have a plain navigation controller with n children

Comment: @matt and i unwind from outermost viewcontroller to whatever intermediate vc, 1st unwind(for:towards) on view controller where unwind button we tapped is called, only after then,  unwind(for:towards)  is called on parent view controller (navigation controller)